# Why is my iPhone 3GS proximity detector not working?

Tags: iphone

Whenever I use the phone on my iPhone 3GS, it detects my face's proximity and dims the screen. However, once the call ends and I take the phone away from my face, the screen does not brighten again until I press the power/wake button, at which point the screen returns to normal.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Some basic info: I'm running iOS 4.1, jailbroken.

Comment: I don't think I'll ever understand why someone intentionally overrides the operating system of their phone in a way that exposes all kinds of internals that a properly-functioning device never exposes, finds that the phone isn't working right, and then wonders why. I'm not giving you a hard time, I just don't get why you'd expect it to function normally.

Comment: Wow, that was an amazingly assholish comment. If it weren't for the fact that it _used_ to work, I wouldn't have asked. Assume, for Bob's sake, that I am not a moron.

Comment: Have you restored it to a non-jailbroken state to see if it solves your problem? I didn't see it in your question so assumed that you had not, hence my comment, but I'm certainly open to being wrong. I take it the problem continued after you removed the OS changes you made, is that right?

Comment: The idea is to seek avenues to solve the problem that don't require me to wipe the device. I'm prepared to restore it if that's the only possible solution, of course, and I'd have to at any rate in order to receive service for it. But I'd rather preserve my current setup if possible.

Comment: Best of luck with it, then. I stand by my initial comment, it still seems like a strange expectation.

Comment: @Matthew be nice :) I have an iPhone 2G jailbroken with iOs 3.1.3 (or the latest for 2G) and a regular 3GS not jailbroken and I just called myself and Proximity Sensor works on both. It's "unlikely" that the jailbroken mechanism has anything to do with a daemon monitoring a proximity (that works with light possibly) sensor, especially if it was working before. But of course, one  never knows.

Comment: @Chris I'd honestly try to restore the phone from "factory" and try. If it works, restore from a Backup and see if the problem is in your specific backup or just a weird thing in the Jailbroken process.

Comment: @Martin I don't know that it's the general jailbroken state, certainly, but that state does allow apps to run that could very well be getting in the way of the daemon. And really, I am being nice: I'm not saying Chris is a bad guy or something actually assholish like "losers jailbreak" or anything. I really am simply expressing my lack of understanding of how someone expects a hacked device that is -- by the very nature of the hack -- exposing its internals to all kinds of weaknesses that would otherwise be protected, and wants the problem solved while leaving everything exposed.

Comment: @Matthew well, I understand your point and I agree that "if you go black, you can't go back", but to be honest, @Chris was not *demanding* a solution or cursing against Apple, he was just asking about it (perhaps not in the most elegant way). In any case, his problem is that "it was working before". But the real question is… before **what**? ;)

Comment: Before some arbitrary point in time; the jailbroken state is as old as the iOS JB release, but the proximity sensor stopped working independently of that, as well as (as far as I can tell) independently of any software install.  That said, I mentioned jailbreaking specifically so that if someone was aware of a _specific_ jailbreak-related cause for this, they could propose it. It was not an invitation to criticize the choice of usage patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember ever reading about a problem with proximity sensors in iPhone 3GS running iOS 4.x. The well-known problem was with iPhone 4, and it was fixed in iOS 4.2.1.

I guess you will have to restore your iPhone, either to verify that your problem was caused by some rogue app you installed via jailbreak or to take the phone to an Apple Store.